# Dynamic reference to the above cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my Excel worksheet, every 25 rows or so (this number is subject to change), a cell in column C contains a progressive number, identifying a set. Right now, there is a simple formula, e.g. in Cell 34:

```
= C9 + 1
```

When The number of rows above C34 changes, the formula updates automatically. No issue with that.

I am now experimenting with a macro that inserts a set in between two existing sets; therefore another number that should fit in the progression, and the following numbers should adapt.

I thought that formulas should change, to find the first number above the current cell and add +1.

Trying a solution from [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/614639-get-first-non-blank-cell-above-certain-cell.html), I came up with the following formula:

```
=LOOKUP("z";$C$9:OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()));-1;0))+1
```

It seems however that it only searches for text, giving a `#N/A`when there is no text and a `#VALUE!` when there is text; if I do not add the +1, it works fine.

I also tried

```
=LOOKUP(2;1/(C$9:C9<>"");C:C)
```

As explained in the link but all I get is `0`

**How do I modify these formulas to give me the expected result?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming than the number of the first set is in `A1`,
enter this formula

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+100,OFFSET(A$1,,,ROW()-1)))+1
```

in the counting cells (`A5`,`A10`, `A16` in the example):

[image]

Then you can insert rows for a new inserted set, for example:

[image]

[image]

When ypu copy the same formula into `C10`,
 the set numbers update accordingly:

[image]

And you can fill the text elements of the set:

[image]

Comment: This works (very well, if I may add), if the first set number is in A1. I tried moving the references to make it work from my cell (C9) but it gives me 0. How do I edit it?

Comment: @laureapresa:  Try 
`=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+100,OFFSET(C$1,,,ROW()-1)))+1`